# Enable button on checkbox selection in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, checkbox

Lot of research and tries but didn't work.My Problem is I want to enable my button on check of at least one checkbox from the available list.

Following is the screen:
[image]

[image]

Initially this button is enabled but my requirement is it should be disabled initially and if at least one of the checkbox is checked then it should be enabled.

Here,I have one view as Create inside which one more partial view is there which displays all the list view with the help of one controller method i.e within my Create view one more view is being rendered which displays all the available list.

If it would have been in one view then I would have easily done this as lot of fiddles are there with jquery by getting the id of the checkbox and passing to one jquery function. I know that I need to check the count for the checkbox in order to make my button enable/disable but again we dont have any change event as that in ASP.

Also on click of add , method for controller is begin triggered as:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(int id, List<MyModel> myModelList)
{
    // code...
}
```

Here once I click on Add button this controller method is triggered where in my parameters(myModelList) I am able to check which checkbox is checked.So, this thing I need to implement on checking any of the checkbox such that the add button will be enabled on click of which I will be able to add my teams.

So how to **implement** this or what I need to do for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: Oops. Added the `:checked` pseudo class

This is how you might do it in jQuery

```
$('#add_button_id').prop('disabled', true); // To disable initially

$(document).on('click', '.checkbox_class', function(){
  if( $('.checkbox_class:checked').length > 0 ){
    $('#add_button_id').prop('disabled', false);
  }
  else{
    $('#add_button_id').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

You'll have to add the id for the button and classes for checkbox as you have in your html code

Comment: It is working patially i.e, initially the button is disabled and on check of any of the checkbox it is being enabled but as soon as I uncheck the checkbox the else condition is not firing ,I tried with alert but everytime it is going to if condition only.Can u pls tell something about this?

Comment: Updated. Sorry, had missed out the most crucial part. :-(

Answer (score 3):

you can do it this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '.checkbox_class', function(){
    if(".checkbox_class:checked").length > 0)
        $('#add_button_id').prop('disabled', false);
    else
        $('#add_button_id').prop('disabled', true);
  }).change();
```

you can also trigger change on page load:

```
$(function(){

  $(".checkbox_class").tirgger('change');

})
```

Comment: Would the `.change()` work? Not tested, just guessing it won't as it'll be fired on the `$(document)` instead of `.checkbox_class`